# Filter CSV rows based on count of column value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am very new to Python and now I am working on a task requiring me to store rows which appears less than k times from a CSV file.

Basically the CSV file has 3 columns. First column is the part I have to consider. So for example if 'a' appeared less than 5 times in that column I need to pick out those records and store them in a new CSV file.

I managed to use panda's `df['column name'].value_counts()` to count how many times each row appeared. Now I am stucking at how to actually pick out those less frequent rows and store them. I have some thoughts such as using a for loop to loop through all rows and use if to check whether certain data in the first column appears less than K times. The part I failed to figure out seems to be how to link the frequency count with certain data in that column.

Below is a screenshot of my data file
[example of my csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7QtJ.png)

Any help is much appreciated! thanks guys!

Comment: Do you really have to use Pandas of this particular work or project or any alternatives is allowed to use ???

Comment: I can use anything I like. Pandas was just one lib i started with. before that I have to hash a column so I started with Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned pandas, and here is a pandas approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data frame
data = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (1, 4, 5),
    (1, 6, 7),
    (9, 10, 11),
    (9, 12, 13),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('x', 'y', 'z'))

# keep rows with value in column 'x' appears at most 'ceiling' times
ceiling = 2
low_freq = df['x'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x <= ceiling].index

# use boolean mask to find rows such that 'x' is in our low_freq list
mask = df['x'].isin(low_freq)

# print results
print(df[mask])

   x   y   z
3  9  10  11
4  9  12  13

# use df[mask].to_csv(...) to write to csv file
```

UPDATE:

Here is a way to 'take apart' the code above.  For example, what is `low_freq`?  This lets you see each step in the transformation -- so you can modify / extend the approach.

```
df['x']
df['x'].value_counts()
df['x'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x <= ceiling]
df['x'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x <= ceiling].index
```

UPDATE 2

Evidently the filtering logic is not working as expected.  Let's try a different approach:

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data frame
data = [(0, 1, 2, ), (1, 1, 4, ), (2, 1, 6, ),
        (3, 9, 10,), (4, 9, 12,), (5, 7, 21,)]
df = (pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('pos_id', 'device_id', 'base_mac'))
      .set_index('pos_id'))
```

Now use `groupby()` to count the number of occurrences of each `device_id`.  This count goes into a new column.

```
df['dev_id_count'] = (df.groupby('device_id')['device_id']
                        .transform('count'))
print(df)

        device_id  base_mac  dev_id_count
pos_id                                   
0               1         2             3
1               1         4             3
2               1         6             3
3               9        10             2
4               9        12             2
5               7        21             1
```

The last step is to filter based on this new column:

```
mask = df['dev_id_count'] <= 2
print(df[mask])
# output not shown, to save space
```

Comment: hey man, thanks A LOT! It really works! if you don't mind I will expand the full story here. In short, I got table with 3 columns, first one is the vital one. It contains alphanumerical characters. Each value is either 4 digits of numbers or 4 alphanumerical characters. the other 2 columns don't really matter. What I try here is to check whether all rows/records in the CSV output conform to K anonymity. Say k = 5, I will like to pick out those records appear less than 5 times and store them for now for later process. Do you think I am on the right track?

Comment: Yes, I think you're on the right track.  I added a short update, showing how to get intermediate results in the pandas code.  This way, you can modify / extend for your project.  Also check out `.groupby()` for counting number of occurrences in a column.

Comment: I really appreciate your help here man however i seem to run into some problem. your example works fine with this method but when i tried it on my real data sheet it seems to be 'wrong'? The original csv data sheet contains 2700 rows or records i say then after using this method i get the output datasheet with 2500 lines. it doesn't seem to be right for me since I already hashed the table. it would be strange if this method can cause almost 80% of the rows 'appear less than k times'. Could you give me a little more clues? I try to upload some screenshots in the question

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean the method you demonstrated caused the problem. I mean the csv output surprised me. previous to the step we are talking about I just hashed the whole csv table. do you think this is the problem of the data itself or did I do something wrong?

Comment: hey man, I just wonder what exactly is the result from your code? does the result CSV file contains all rows which appear less than K times or are those rows appear more than K times?

Comment: Hi, the filtering is done in the `low_freq = ...` line.  Specifically, we keep rows such that `x <= ceiling` is true (in the lambda expression).  You can modify this to keep numbers above a threshold, below a threshold, or between lower and upper bounds.

Comment: thanks buddy! Could you explain what does the 'index' do at the end of the filtering line? I tried to remove it and ended up with an empty dataset

Comment: Sure, here is the intuition:  1) *find* the index values (i.e., row labels) that meet our criterial in the `low_freq` line; and 2) *use* these index values to select from `df['x']` -- It's like SQL join, or set intersection.

Comment: wow, now that's very clear to me. you are amazing man! i ain't sure if i need to open up a new post or not but if you still happy to help me a bit more here is the last question. Did you see the screenshot? So i have removed the very right column, only left pos id, device_name and base_mac columns. then I used your code to filter it. the result seems shocking. I got most (2500 out of 2700)lines which appear less than the threshold (I set it to 2 in this case). do you know what can possibly go wrong? I am expecting way less rows which appear less than K times here

Comment: Hi, please check out Update 2 -- we can use `groupby()` to count number of times we see each value.  The `transform()` function may not be needed here, but it will make number of rows in output be same as number of rows in input.

Comment: thanks man. i don't think i gonna get it anymore lol. The data source comes from some detection devices and I am suppose to process the data on the fly. So i am afraid introducing a new column won't be ideal. I tried it out tho however it seems to be the same as our previous methods. maybe my problem is with the dataset itself. maybe it can't be k anonymity?

Comment: Sounds like verifying the assumptions / properties of the data set is a good next step.  Here is a good reference on making a pandas pipeline: https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a standard library version:

```
import csv

THRESHOLD = 5

def get_data(filename, column, threshold=THRESHOLD):
    """Return list of dict of rows where count of the column is smaller than the threshold and the headers of the CSV file"""
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        # get all rows where there's NO data in the column
        data = [line for line in csv_reader if not line.get(column)]
        if len(data) < threshold:
            return data, csv_reader.fieldnames

def write_data(filename, data, headers):
    """Write data to a CSV"""
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer.writerows(data)

data, headers = get_data(filename='file.csv', column='a')
write_data(filename='filter.csv', data=data, headers=headers)
```